# MySQL compare different values in case when function

Tags: mysql, case

In this query I use the CASE WHEN function to compare variables values in two different conditions. The problem is the number, because return a value = 1, but the correct result is NULL (20 is > of 8).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        case 
            when '20'>= '8' then null
            when '20'< '8' then '1'
        ELSE '0'
        end checkValue
    FROM DUAL;
```

How to resolve this problem?

The query run correctly if change 8 with 08. This solution is not applicable to because from variable arrive numers: 10 100 1000 units.

Thanks

Comment: try: `when 20>= 8 then null
            when 20< 8 then '1'`

Comment: @OtoShavadze: without '' run correctly, but I receive a variables and the variables is a string

Answer (score 0):

I have change the field type from VARCHAR to DECIMAL and in this case work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you want compare string  remember that string '20' < '8'  so  'AB' is < 'C'

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        case 
            when '20'>= '08' then null
            when '20'< '08' then '1'
        ELSE '0'
        end checkValue
    FROM DUAL;
```

otherwise if you want a number compare then you  shoudl convert tne string as number

Answer (score -1):

You need just cast strings to some numeric data type and then compare, for example

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    case 
        when cast('20' as signed)>= cast('8' as signed) then null
        when cast('20' as signed)< cast('8' as signed) then '1'
    ELSE '0'
    end checkValue
FROM DUAL;
```

Side note: `DISTINCT` no makes sense in this particular case

Comment: Thanks for your solution.